# Understanding some autocmd events

Tags: vimrc

When logging autocommand events, I came across a few ones that seem a bit strange:

1. `User` -- seems to be logged very frequently, though the vim help really only mentions "it's not a real event and only executed by `:doautocmd`. What is this event, and when/why would it be fired?
2. `SafeState`, `SafeStateAgain` -- these seem to be the most commonly invoked event types. Vim says this means `'When nothing is pending'` -- why would this event be needed then? That is, what could it be used for / why would an autocmd ever use it?
3. `CmdlineChange` -- This is invoked ad nausem on any undo function, For example pressing `u` (see image below). Why this this invoked so frequently on `undo`?

[image]

4. `CursorHold` -- I get this occassionally (`CursorMoved` seems much more clear/consistent). It seems to be invoked if I don't move my cursor for ~5s, but that's not really a precise picture of it. Does this keep firing every 5s (or whatever time-frame this is), or is it only fired once?
5. Finally, when logging these events the help section is blank! Why does that occur? Here is a 15-second video of what the help-section looks like when I have logged on: https://gyazo.com/5fa1e1e7907c8cb4b3a5bbdf1574c82e.

Comment: Have you already read the help for each of these events (`:h User` and so on) before asking a question? Have you tried to do the same with your plugins disabled?

Comment: CursorHold is controlled by a setting. User is used by plugins to create hooks